# How to combine multiple actions in blender 2.90 in a single baked strip to render?

Tags: animation, nla-editor, actions

My goal is to combine all my animations actions (clips) into a single baked animation. I found a youtube tutorial but is not useful for me.

LINK (MY FAIL)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFV0oS7YVHQ

active the subtitles if you want.

I need to combine all of this actions.
[image]

as you can see there are many in a separate tracks. all of them start at 1 frame. the range is from 1-70 frames (most of them are from 1-24)

is the order importan? I mean is it necessary to use as this way ?

[image]

I ve found this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w78xUaPV0ls but is not work for me..

[image]

when I move one of the strip to the right...and hit play to see if the "other" animation (animation 2) is running, my character is stopped in animation 1... not matter how many strips o tracks put to the right in the time line of the NLA editor...I can not join...

by the other hand, I do not sure If I need to use "blend in" or "blend out" I put blend in and blend out value of "2.000" but not works...
If I put "replace" mode the animations is destroyed.

I decided to test with "extrapolation"

in the next "gift" (giazo links below) I try to show you the transition betwenn one animation and the next one (to not waste time I only testing 1 to 2 animation ,probably I need to make a test if works with 2 animations,so I can put more and more actions soon, have logic?).

https://gyazo.com/808fdd304a4bc1bdc20238f82890d070
thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130272/discussion-on-question-by-rg1988-how-to-combine-multiple-actions-in-blender-2-90).

Answer (score 1):

this might be too manual, but

1. open NLA editor AND dope sheet editor.
2. LINK action strip into an NLA track
3. press tab in NLA editor, the action strip should turn green (it should at least turn a different color). the green action strip should be displayed in the dope sheet as well, which leads too--
4. press "a" twice in the dope sheet, copy the keyframes from the dope sheet.
5. create a new NLA track & create a keyframe for this new track
6. paste the keyframes that were copied previously

END.
now you can repeat the process, keep in mind that youll have to align each new pasted action from the very last keyframe.

Comment: How to "link" the strip? I only know how to push down the strip action or stash. thank however